# Bootstrap dropdown menu not working

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am a jQuery beginner and am trying to get the hang of it by using the `Twitter-Bootstrap` dropdown feature, but nothing drops down when I click on the "Google" `li`. I was pretty confused about why it wasn't working so I just started throwing things into my own code from the code from the [example dropdown](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#dropdowns) menu on the Bootstrap website. That would be the explanation for any code that seems superfluous.

Here is my **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2aaNS/)**.

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('dropdown-toggle').click(function() {
        $(this).dropdown();
    });   
    $('li a').hover(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("hover");
    });    
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <ul class="nav">
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a id="drop1" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" href="#">Google</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="drop1">
                <li>
                    <a href="www.google.com">Google</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="www.gmail.com">Gmail</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="www.facebook.com">Facebook</a>
        </li> 
    </ul>
</div>
```

Why is the drop-down menu not working?

Side question: I had my navigation menu `li`s styled so that when you hovered over each, the background color would not change but the text would become a lighter grey. After I linked to Bootstrap, hovering now changes the background color to white and the text color to blue. Why?

Comment: Firstly, `dropdown-toggle` should be `.dropdown-toggle` in your jQuery `click()` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of things. The way you have your drop-downs set up, you don't need the click trigger to open up. Also your dropdowns were opening up but it was showing up in the scroll. With a couple of changes you can make it work.

```
.nav {
    overflow:visible; /*Changed from auto*/
}

#container {
    background-color:#333333;
    width: 100%;
    margin:auto;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgb(34, 34, 34), rgb(17, 17, 17));
    display:inline-block; /*Added this to get your background color to get applied*/
}
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xvyxB/)

You can safely remove your `dropdown-toggle` click event, even though the selector was wrong, as @Zenith mentioned. Bootstrap takes care of it using `data-toggle="dropdown"` on the markup.

For your second question. Bootstrap styles overrides your styles.
So apply these styles:

instead of `.hover`  use this: to override BS styles:-

```
.nav>li>a.hover, .nav>li>a:focus {
    color:#C9C9C9;
    background-color:#333333;
}
```

#### [Full Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/z6YSS/)

Also you probably don't need

```
 $('li a').hover(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("hover");
    });
```

Instead, you can handle it with:

```
.nav>li>a:hover, .nav>li>a:focus {
        color:#C9C9C9;
        background-color:#333333;
    }
```

Comment: @Zenith Yes you are right BS takes care of it. Thanks for the edit.. :)

Comment: @PSL thank you! I hadn't realized that you can use BS just using data attributes. A few follow-ups (sorry):

1: If BS overrode my style set by my hover jQuery event handler, why does it not override my style when it's set by `.nav>li>a:hover`?

2: Could you explain the rationale behind making `#container` `display:inline-block`?

3: The background color was actually accidentally left over from before I had applied a gradient background. Is there any reason why I would want to include both?

4: Why does my drop-down menu look so funky (i.e. have a middle divider and whitespace on the right)?

Answer (score 0):

you might want to add jquery to your fiddle under frameworks & extensions then under external resources enter http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js and click the plus icon.

remove the overflow:auto on #nav and you can actually remove most of the javascript and you will see the nav will dropdown on the click you just then need to style it somewhat

Comment: I'm having trouble figuring out how to remove the vertical black bar and whitespace in my dropdown menu. How would I remedy that?